# How to find the filename without path?

Tags: linux, find, filenames

Currently, I have a function to find the filename, size and type; however, it includes the path as well, which I don't really need.

`find . -type f -exec stat --format="%n %s %F"`

which returns

`directory/file size file type`

Is there any way I could get it to show only the name of the file without the path using find, or do I have to use something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using GNU `find` (which I’m guessing is the case, given the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag), you can use its `-printf` action:

```
find . -type f -printf "%p %s %y\n"
```

(`%y` gives the same information as `stat`’s `%F`, as a single letter).

Alternatively, also assuming GNU find, use `-execdir` so that the executed command happens in the containing directory:

```
find . -type f -execdir stat --format="%n %s %F" {} +
```

Comment: the alternative sort of gives me what im looking for. however it returns the filenames as   `./filename` instead of just the filename, do you know if there is anyway if i could change this?